# tf.while_loop gives wrong result when it runs in parallel

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to update a two dimensional `tf.variable` inside a `tf.while_loop` in tensorflow by row. For this reason, I use the `tf.assign` method. The problem is that with my implementation and `parallel_iterations>1` the result is wrong. With `parallel_iterations=1` the result is correct. The code is like this:

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 100]), dtype=tf.int64)

i = tf.constant(0)
def condition(i, var):
    return tf.less(i, 100)

def body(i, var):
    updated_row = method() # This method returns a [1, 100] tensor which is the updated row for the variable
    temp = tf.assign(a[i], updated_row)
    return [tf.add(i, 1), temp]

z = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [i, a], back_prop=False, parallel_iterations=10)
```

The iterations are completely independent and I do not know what is the problem.

Strangely If I change the code like this:

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 100]), dtype=tf.int64)

i = tf.constant(0)
def condition(i, var):
    return tf.less(i, 100)

def body(i, var):
    zeros = lambda: tf.zeros([100, 100], dtype=tf.int64)
    temp = tf.Variable(initial_value=zeros, dtype=tf.int64)
    updated_row = method() # This method returns a [1, 100] tensor which is the updated row for the variable
    temp = tf.assign(temp[i], updated_row)
    return [tf.add(i, 1), temp]

z = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [i, a], back_prop=False, parallel_iterations=10)
```

the code gives the correct outcome for `parallel_iterations>1`. Can someone explain me what is going on here and give me an efficient solution to update the variable because the original variable I want to update is huge and the solution I found is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use variables for this, you can just generate the row-updated tensor on the loop body:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def method(i):
    # Placeholder logic
    return tf.cast(tf.range(i, i + 100), tf.float32)

def condition(i, var):
    return tf.less(i, 100)

def body(i, var):
    # Produce new row
    updated_row = method(i)
    # Index vector that is 1 only on the row to update
    idx = tf.equal(tf.range(tf.shape(a)[0]), i)
    idx = tf.cast(idx[:, tf.newaxis], var.dtype)
    # Compose the new tensor with the old one and the new row
    var_updated = (1 - idx) * var + idx * updated_row
    return [tf.add(i, 1), var_updated]

# Start with zeros
a = tf.zeros([100, 100], tf.float32)
i = tf.constant(0)
i_end, a_updated = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [i, a], parallel_iterations=10)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(a_updated))
```

Output:

```
[[  0.   1.   2. ...  97.  98.  99.]
 [  1.   2.   3. ...  98.  99. 100.]
 [  2.   3.   4. ...  99. 100. 101.]
 ...
 [ 97.  98.  99. ... 194. 195. 196.]
 [ 98.  99. 100. ... 195. 196. 197.]
 [ 99. 100. 101. ... 196. 197. 198.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code can run for 'parallel_iterations>1' and produce the correct result but for some reason doesn't run in parallel. You can check it for yourself on the example you wrote. Increase the rows from a to 2000 and run some benchmarks for different parallel iterations.

Comment: @TheodosisSiomos I do not really know well how `parallel_iterations` is supposed to work, but I got somewhat confusing benchmark results. If I run this code in CPU, then `parallel_iterations` does not seem to have any effect, like you say. If I run it on a GPU, for a `(1000, 1000)` array I get ~280ms with `parallel_iterations` set to `1`, ~205ms with `2`, ~170ms with `3` and ~165ms with `4` or more.

Comment: I do not know what is going on here. And the code seems solid to me. I will try to find out. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In tf.function I've found the following:

> Key Point: Any Python side-effects (appending to a list, printing with print, etc) will only happen once, when func is traced. To have side-effects executed into your tf.function they need to be written as TF ops:

I'm pretty sure that's what's going on here. You're expecting **a** to change but that is a "side effect" ( https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/fopp/Functions/SideEffects.html ) which tensorflow does not fully support. When you change a to temp you're no longer relying on the side effect and the code works.